# Anchor links inside iframe require two clicks on iOS Mobile Safari

Tags: html, iframe, mobile-safari

I have an iframe that contains a link to an anchor element, which is also within the iframe. On mobile Safari, the first touch is ignored; it requires two touches to jump to the link target.

Example: http://ridiculousfish.com/iframepain/outer.html and touch the Click Me!. This requires two touches to jump to the Link Target on mobile Safari.

Bizarrely, if I remove some text ("This Text Matters") above the link, the issue no longer reproduces. Fixed example: http://ridiculousfish.com/iframepain/outer2.html

How can I make the link work on the first touch?

Note there is no JavaScript, hover, or cross-page business involved.